# Background image of the section to Specific Height

Tags: html, css, styles, sections

What I really want to achieve is that to put the background image to a specific height like I have one section which contains two divs I gave the section a background image 
which is

```
    background-image: linear-gradient(-207deg, #0EC573, #0093FF);
```

Now I want to achieve is the background image covers the whole of the **Second div** and some part of the **first** div

FULL CODE

```
 <section class="company py-4" >
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
          <div class="mt-5 px-3">
                <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="4000">
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                    </ol>

                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="{!! asset('images/Company/02.jpg') !!}">
                            <div class="mt-5 ">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item ">
                            <div class="justify-content-center align-items-center">
                                <img class="img-fluid" src="{!! asset('images/Company/01.jpg') !!}">
                            </div>
                            <div class="mt-5 ">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="{!! asset('images/Company/03.jpg') !!}">
                            <div class="mt-5 ">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="{!! asset('images/Company/04.jpg') !!}">
                            <div class="mt-5 ">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  <!--   <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button"data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a> -->

                </div>
            </div>            
      </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
               <div class="col-12 "> 
                <h1 class="text-left heading">Company</h1>
                <p class="text-left description"> ALL THE DESCRIPTION</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: share your full code ..!

Comment: the complete code is shared. anything more detailed please let me know

Comment: you mean the `conteiner` divs??

Comment: yes thats what i reaaly want

Comment: @Malik you should add the rest of your container CSS to the question also. There is not a lot of context to go from at the moment.

Comment: i don't have any CSS for the container the only first div have is the carousel

Comment: @frontendzzzguy the code is shared

Comment: @Malik what do you mean some part ???

Comment: @frontendzzzguy let me know if you want to know anything else? thank you

Comment: @Malik do you mean only the part of image or the list ??

Comment: @לבנימלכה by some part means half of the first div

Comment: @לבנימלכה the first section contains the carousel images want to cover some part of it

Comment: see my answer please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use it (See JSFiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/Lfxja1e5/7/) :**

```
 background-size: 100% 70%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

**If you want it in bottom use:

```
background-position: bottom;
```

```css
 .company{
      background-image:linear-gradient(-207deg,#0EC573, #0093FF);
     background-size: 100% 70%;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: bottom;
    }
```

```html
<section class="company py-4" >
            <div class="container d1">
                <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
              <div class="mt-5 px-3">
                    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="4000">
                        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                        </ol>

                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="carousel-item active">
                                <img class="img-fluid" src="{!! asset('images/Company/02.jpg') !!}">
                                <div class="mt-5 ">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item ">
                                <div class="justify-content-center align-items-center">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" src="{!! asset('images/Company/01.jpg') !!}">
                                </div>
                                <div class="mt-5 ">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="img-fluid" src="{!! asset('images/Company/03.jpg') !!}">
                                <div class="mt-5 ">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <img class="img-fluid" src="{!! asset('images/Company/04.jpg') !!}">
                                <div class="mt-5 ">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      <!--   <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button"data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                        </a> -->

                    </div>
                </div>            
          </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container d2">
                <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
                   <div class="col-12 "> 
                    <h1 class="text-left heading">Company</h1>
                    <p class="text-left description"> ALL THE DESCRIPTION</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: Does it helps you?

Comment: its not because it should be in the bottom

Comment: and it helps giving a way to solve the problem but still stucked

Comment: If you want it in bottom use:

`background-position: bottom;`

Comment: I worte it in my wanser

Comment: background-position:bottom work but the issue is the background image should be consistent